# How can i move object up and down infinitely in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to move object up and down infinitely in unity5(2d game)
start position is current position and target position is current position + y vector(0, y, 0) 
and i hope to control object's speed.

Answer (score 1):

public class moleMove : MonoBehaviour {

```
Vector3 current_position;
float direction = 1.0f;
float speed = 1.5f;
float heightlimit = 0.8f;
float timecount = 0.0f;
float timelimit = 2.5f;

void Start(){
    current_position = this.transform.position;
}

void Update() {

    transform.Translate (0, direction*speed*Time.deltaTime * 1, 0);


    if (transform.position.y >current_position.y+heightlimit) {
        direction = -1;
    }
    if (transform.position.y <current_position.y){
        direction = 0;
        timecount = timecount + Time.deltaTime;

        if (timecount > timelimit) {
            direction = 1;
            timecount = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

}